# Make a Messagebox.Show("Message"); stay till a function gets executed c#-ms word add in

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have a messagebox before a function starts, like this .

```
Messagebox.show("Please wait till all links are verfied");
```

Make this stay till the below code gets completely executed ,if possible disable the ok button in the message box and enable it later or just disable the ok button and close the message box once the function gets executed

```
foreach(word.hyperlink link in links)

{

try

{

//do something

}

catch

{

//do something

}

}

Messagebox.show("All links are verified");
```

Any ideas are appreciated.Thanks for your time :)

Comment: You should make your own dialog (using a form), and display it modally until your process completes.

Comment: Why dont you use a Form instead of message box ?

Comment: Won't using Form.ShowDialog() stop code after it from executing until it's closed?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Message Box by creating a form and add message and buttons to it.Make sure that add code like form.Show() instead of form.ShowDialog();

Comment: But I'am trying to use this as an add in in ms word by customizing a ribbon toolbar,so in other words I can only use the default messagebox.show for c# vsto.Forms wont work in that ..if there is a way to get this working ,can you please elaborate on how I can do this